# PowerDNS Recursor – Private / Public IP

Tags: ip, bind, powerdns

Sorry to bother you I wanted to know if it was possible that the pdns_recursor uses an ip address for all that is public and one for all that is private (or "internal"). Indeed, I looked in the various settings of the configuration file and I did not find anything.

For example, on my infrastructur :

- If a client requests www.google.com, the client will have to query "public dns" and thus have a public address.
- While if he queries private.com he will have to query a private
  Authoritative dns and he will need a private IP address (because I need his "geolocation").

Thank you in advance